# I would like to create a folder to store images in C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//Directory where images are stored on the server
String dist = "~/ImageStorage";

//get the file name of the posted image
string imgName = image.FileName.ToString();

String path = Server.MapPath("~/ImageStorage");//Path

//Check if directory exist
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath(path)); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
}

//sets the image path
string imgPath = path + "/" + imgName;

//get the size in bytes that
int imgSize = image.PostedFile.ContentLength;


if (image.PostedFile != null)
{

    if (image.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)//Check if image is greater than 5MB
    {
        //Save image to the Folder
        image.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));

    }

}
```

I would like to create a directory of folder on the server were the application is, the folder should store all images uploaded by users. the code above is not working:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   'c:/users/lameck/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient/BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient/ImageStorage' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: 'c:/users/lameck/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient/BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient/ImageStorage' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Source Error:

Line 36:             if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
Line 37:             {
Line 38:                 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath(path)); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
Line 39:             }
Line 40:

Source File: c:\Users\Lameck\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient\BentleyCarOwnerAssociatioServiceClient\registerCar.aspx.cs    Line: 38

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use MapPath() twice for the same path.

Old Code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath(path)); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
```

Corrected Code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
```

**EDIT:** Also corrected this:

```
string imgPath = path + "/" + imgName;
```

To this:

```
string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imgName);
```

**whole corrected code:**

```
  //get the file name of the posted image
    string imgName = image.FileName.ToString();

    String path = Server.MapPath("~/ImageStorage");//Path

    //Check if directory exist
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
    }

    //sets the image path
    string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imgName);

    //get the size in bytes that
    int imgSize = image.PostedFile.ContentLength;


    if (image.PostedFile != null)
    {

        if (image.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)//Check if image is greater than 5MB
        {
            //Save image to the Folder
            image.SaveAs(imgPath);

        }

    }
```